# Sockets - How to find out what port and address I'm assigned

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm having trouble figuring this out - I'm working with sockets in C using this guide - http://binarii.com/files/papers/c_sockets.txt

I'm trying to automatically get my ip and port using:

```
server.sin_port = 0;              /* bind() will choose a random port*/
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;  /* puts server's IP automatically */
...
...
bind(int fd, struct sockaddr *my_addr,int addrlen); // Bind function
```

After a successful bind, how do I find out what IP and Port I'm actually assigned?

Comment: Actually what's happening when you specify `INADDR_ANY` isn't that it puts the server's IP in automatically, what it does is finds all interfaces, and binds to each one of them. Therefore, you have many right answers to your question.

Comment: Hmm - thanks jer. An assignment I'm working on requires me to automatically obtain the IP and port using the code specified, but I'm to print the server address and port for the client to connect to on the screen. This is what I'm trying to figure out how to do. If I use the sockaddr struct, I just get 0.0.0.0 and port 0.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496302/how-can-i-obtain-the-local-tcp-port-and-ip-address-of-my-client-program

Comment: Actually it doesn't 'bind to each one of them'. It doesn't bind to *any* of them. Rather it tells the stack to *act as though* it was bound to *all* of them. That's why it's called INADDR_ANY.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If it's a server socket, you should call [`listen()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/listen.html) on your socket, and then [`getsockname()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsockname.html) to find the port number on which it is listening:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
socklen_t len = sizeof(sin);
if (getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len) == -1)
    perror("getsockname");
else
    printf("port number %d\n", ntohs(sin.sin_port));
```

As for the IP address, if you use `INADDR_ANY` then the server socket can accept connections to any of the machine's IP addresses and the server socket itself does not have a specific IP address.  For example if your machine has two IP addresses then you might get two incoming connections on this server socket, each with a different local IP address.  You can use `getsockname()` on the socket for a specific connection (which you get from `accept()`) in order to find out which local IP address is being used on that connection.

Comment: Thanks mark4o - That works great! But I'm still having trouble getting the address - I still get 0.0.0.0 - any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The server socket does not have a specific IP address, and the machine may have multiple IP addresses.  If you just want to get one of the machine's addresses, check out this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer

Comment: Thanks for this code sample. If anyone is confused about what sock is, it is the file descriptor of the socket.

Comment: What about UDP: If I send on a socket that has Port `0` assigned, how can I find out what the sending port number actually is? (It is different from TCP)

Comment: Note that you do not have to actually call `listen`, this should work for both TCP and UDP sockets as long as they are bound first.

Answer (score 6):

The comment in your code is wrong. `INADDR_ANY` doesn't put server's IP automatically'. It essentially puts **0.0.0.0**, for the reasons explained in mark4o's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4047837/12892).