# bind() server socket to any port always gives port no. 0

Tags: c++, sockets

I need to bind my server to a dynamic port (use an ephermal port) but call to bind() when port is specified to be 0 (which means any random port) is always binding the server to port 0.

//Sample code snippet

```
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
   error("ERROR opening socket");
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(INADDR_ANY);  //randomly selected port
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
  error("ERROR on binding");

listen(sockfd,5);

printf("Port no. is %d",ntohs (serv_addr.sin_port));
close(sockfd);
```

Comment: Why are you setting `sin_port` to `htons(INADDR_ANY)` instead of `0`? This doesn't make sense semantically speaking. Additionally, you should use `getsockname` to find the actual socket your server is listening on.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be inventing your own semantics.

If you look at the [`bind(2)` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) you'll see that the second argument is `const struct sockaddr *addr` and yet you are expecting it to be updated after the call to `bind()`.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046616/sockets-how-to-find-out-what-port-and-address-im-assigned) to find out how to determine which port was assigned within `bind()`.